# Restlet client-server streaming using interfaces

Tags: java, client-server, restlet

I'd like to do something similar to the [example posted in restlet's site (first applicaiton)](http://restlet.org/learn/guide/2.1/introduction/first-steps/first-application) - with one difference:

**I want to stream data - not use primitive types - using an interface.**

I want to define some kind of an interface between the client and the server, stream data between them and let restlet handle transmit the data seamlessly.

Example of what I have in mind:

```
interface Streaming {
  InputStream startStream(String streamId);
}
```

When the client invokes a call, it starts reading from the inputstream. The server receives the call and starts providing the stream by creating an inputstream (for example, a video file, or just some raw data). Restlet should be reading from the inputstream on the server side and provide the data as an inputstream on the client side.

**Any idea how can I achieve this?** A code sample or link to one would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Look at ReadableRepresentation.  I've done something similar to send back huge CSV files as they're built on the server.

Comment: I don't know if this is possible. I'll be glad to have a client server java example of streaming (ReadableRepresentation?) - couldn't find any using goole :(

Answer (score 1):

Below's an example code of what I learned so far - **an interface with streaming capavilities and a client-server streaming example**.

I haven't yet added parameters to the interface and it's only download - no upload yet.

**Interface:**

```
public interface DownloadResource {
    public ReadableRepresentation download();
}
```

**Interface with protocol:** (separation between logic and technology):

```
public interface DownloadResourceProtocol extends DownloadResource {
    @Get
    @Override
    public ReadableRepresentation download();
}
```

**Client:**

```
ClientResource cr = new ClientResource("http://10.0.2.2:8888/download/");
cr.setRequestEntityBuffering(true);
DownloadResource downloadResource = cr.wrap(DownloadResourceProtocol.class);
// Remote invocation - seamless:
Representation representation = downloadResource.download();
// Using data:
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
IOUtils.copy(representation.getStream(), byteArrayOutputStream);
byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
Log.i("Byte array: " + Arrays.toString(byteArray));
```

**Server:**

```
public class DownloadResourceImpl extends ServerResource implements DownloadResourceProtocol {
    @Override
    public ReadableRepresentation download() {
        InputStreamChannel inputStreamChannel;
        try {
            inputStreamChannel = new InputStreamChannel(new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}));
            return new ReadableRepresentation(inputStreamChannel, MediaType.ALL);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Configuration:**

```
public class SampleApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
        Router router = new Router(getContext());
        router.attach("/download/", DownloadResourceImpl.class);
        return router;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this addresses your problem completely, but one approach is to create a thread that streams data back to the client using ReadableRepresentation and a Pipe.

Create a pipe:

```
Pipe pipe = Pipe.open();
```

Create a representation like this:

```
ReadableRepresentation r = new ReadableRepresentation(pipe.source(), mediatype);
```

Start a separate thread that writes batches of bytes to the pipe like this:

```
pipe.sink().write(ByteBuffer.wrap(someBytes));
```

return the representation to the client.

Comment: I'm trying to create a client-server interface based streaming. I don't see how can I achieve it using ReadableRepresentation. How does the interface look like?

Comment: I'm really not sure what you mean now.  Are you trying to implement a server, a client or both?  My answer is about how to stream data from a RESTlet server using a RESTlet Representation.

Comment: Both client and server - using the same java interface - making the connection seamless.